# How to say "Japanese notes" in Japanese?

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese

I feel a bit silly asking this question, but... How do you say "Japanese notes" (or any other language) in Japanese? I've been searching on the Internet and I've found "日本のメモ", but what about the "語" kanji? I thought it would be "日本語のメモ".

By the way, I've also seen that notes are "ノート" too. Are both "ノート" and "メモ" correct in this context?

Ta very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The confusion arises from context. It would help to know exactly what the context for "Japanese Notes" is. As you might be able to tell, in English, the combination can mean several things, such as:

- Notes about Japan
- Notes from a Japanese person
- Notes from Japanese people in general
- Notes about Japanese (as a school subject)
- Notes about the Japanese language
- Notes in the Japanese language

...etc.

Add to this the fact that a "Note" can be scribbled on a memo pad, a notebook, a piece of paper, an email, or even a word document on your PC, and you can see where some of the confusion begins.

Assuming that the proper context is, based on your question, "Japanese Notes" as in the title of a notebook you keep with notes about the Japanese language as you study it, I would say that this might be translated as 日本語｛にほんご｝のノート.

If you mean to refer to the specific content of the notebook, you might say 日本語のメモ instead. Think on this sentence:

> 日本語｛にほんご｝の授業｛じゅぎょう｝のメモはノートに書｛か｝きます。
>   I write my Japanese class notes in a notebook.

To disambiguate, here's a few key points:

> 日本｛にほん｝
>   Japan
>
> 日本語｛にほんご｝
>   Japanese (language)
>
> メモ
>   a memo pad where someone might write reminder notes, or, also, a note in the sense of the message captured
>
> ノート
>   a notebook (the kind you write things in for school subjects)

As for other languages, you'd replace 日本語｛にほんご｝ for the language which you're referring to. For example, English would be 英語｛えいご｝, Spanish would be スペイン語｛ご｝, and so on.

Comment: I meant the title of the notebook. It has been really very useful. Thank you very much!

Comment: @istrasci I apologise. I translated the sentence from my native language and I didn’t know that it could mean more than one thing in English. I’ll try to be more careful next time